# contacts.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does that mean `contacts.map` is not a function? I am trying to get a data from a contacts array list that I create, and how to show a buttons inside the panel, when I click each button, the screen should show different information base on the data that I fetch from API, however, when I'm trying to fetch API the buttons are not displayed in the screen anymore and the avatar image that I want to show on top of the information is also not displayed in the panel anymore.

index.js

```
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contacts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata();
  }

  fetchdata() {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({contacts : res.data});
      });
  }

  render(){
    const {contacts} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="panel">
          {contacts.map(contact => (
          <div class="panel">

            <Panel
              avatar={contact.picture}
            />
              <li class="flex-container">
                <Button title="user">
                  <Panel user={contact.name} />
                </Button>
              </li>
          </div>
            ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

ProfilePanel.js

```
const style={
  borderRadius: 150,
}



class Panel extends Component {

  render() {
    const { avatar,  user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="Panel">
        <div class="panels">
          <div className="avatar">
            <img src={avatar} style={style}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <h2 className="user">{user}</h2>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Panel;
```

Comment: Can you maybe add a json answer that would come from the server?

Answer (score 1):

> contacts.map is not a function

gives you a hint, that `contacts` does not have a `.map` function which in turn indicates, that `contacts` is not an `Array`. As your initial `state.contacts` is an empty `Array` the data you fetch and assign through `setState` cannot be an `Array`, thus introducing the problem. Probably you are missing a `.contacts`

```
this.setState({contacts: res.data.contacts})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the values of your data use this

`this.setState({contacts: res.data.results})`

The error that you're getting tells us that the data you're receiving is not an array. So for better debugging, log everything to the console to get a better understanding of what you're getting back from the url.

Comment: However, after I change to this.setState({contacts: res.data.results}), it shows me Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h2 (created by Panel)
    in div (created by Panel)
    in div (created by Panel)
    in Panel (created by App)
    in div (created by Button)
    in Button (created by App)
    in li (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App    
what's wrong in here and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your Button tag should be renamed to button. That is what maybe is causing the error, because you don't have a custom Button element being imported in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set destruction default value.

changing 'const {contacts} = this.state'; to 'const { contacts = [] } = this.state;'.